# Spring Webflow Scope 'static' variable

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, transition

I have a question about the `set` functionality in a `transition`.

Is there a way to initially **set** a variable to a `flowScope` .

This is my code:

```
<set name="flowScope.uebergreifenderEreignisListMode" value="requestParameters.uebergreifenderEreignisListMode" type="java.lang.String" />
```

on my `xhtml` page I have to set it like:

```
`<f:param name="uebergreifenderEreignisListMode" value="AF_AM" />
```

since I'm setting it very often I'd like to remove this redundancy, and set it directly in the scope.

Is there a way to do so?

I couldn't find any info at the spring webflow documentation.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found out, you can set `'static'` variables in the `on-entry` event.

So for my example this would mean:

```
<on-entry>
       <set name="flowScope.uebergreifenderEreignisListMode" value="'AF_AM'"/>
</on-entry>
```

As a result I don't have to set this variable explicit in the xhtml page and it's always `'AF_AM'`

I hope I can save some future readers time, since this took me like an hour to find out.